# How to generate template based Excel files using Azure v2 functions

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, azure-functions, system.drawing

I am trying to set up a template based Excel file rendering service using Azure functions. It should be possible to fill an Excel template with data from backend and return the generated file as result of the Azure function/web service.

The problem is: all Excel frameworks I've tried so far depend on System.Drawing, which, [for good reasons](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions), is not supported by Azure v2 functions. [Open XML SDK for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) could probably do the job, but for my purpose it's too low level, i.e. I am searching for a framework that makes it easier to fill in data in templates than operating on XML level.

I've already tried the following frameworks:

- Spire.XLS
- ClosedXML
- SpreadsheetLight

and I expect most of the other frameworks out there to behave similar. All of them lead to the same exception:

`System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Drawing.Common: System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.`

The thing is: I do not need the framework to be capable of formatting the spreadsheet from within the code, it should just fill in raw data into existing, formatted templates.

Any experience with this issue/suggestions? Does anyone know a framework developed on top of OpenXML SDK without adding formatting Features using System.Drawing?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use the OpenXML SDK?

Comment: Because it's a too complicated yet powerful SDK for my purpose. I am searching for an easy way to fill manually prepared template Excels using kind of a wildcard replacement system. ClosedXML does exactly what I need using a maximum of 5 LOCs, unfortunately it loads System.Drawing somewhere inside.

It works likes this:

`XLTemplate template = new XLTemplate(templateFilename);
template.AddVariable(myObjectContainingAllNecessaryData);
template.Generate();
template.SaveAs(destinationFilename);`

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not using Azure functions. Instead I deployed the web service to a .NET Core web application using the ClosedXML library i described above.